# App crashes when using view model in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, lazycolumn

```
@HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AppRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    fun getLiveData(date: LocalDate): LiveData<List<Task>> {
        ...
    }
}
```

My screen:

```
@Composable
fun TaskScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, taskViewModel: TaskViewModel = 
viewModel()) {
val date = LocalDate.now()
val tasks = taskViewModel.getLiveData(date = date).observeAsState()
tasks.value?.let { items ->
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(items) { task ->
          ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes with the following exception:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mycodelab.test2.viewmodel.TaskDayViewModel.<init> []
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
```

This is my first attempt at using jetpack compose.

Comment: ```TaskViewModel = 
viewModel()``` - try - ```= hiltViewModel()``` instead

Comment: How do I mark this comment as the right answer?

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Glad it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewModel` when using Hilt in Compose becomes `hiltViewModel`, so your code would look like this:

```
fun TaskScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, taskViewModel: TaskViewModel = 
hiltViewModel()) {}
```

Comment: And in case `hiltViewModel()` is not found, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75975062/3991578